# Wifi connection problem after T450s goes standby

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I had Ubuntu 14.04 on my T450s and had no Wifi problem at all.
Now i have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 when i have a lot of tabs open and if i close my laptop and it goes stand by.
when i open my laptop again the wifi connection is lost until i reboot the computer which is really annoying because i lose all my open tabs and need to reopen my directories.

Comment: Try running `sudo dhclient` the next time it happens. May or may not help - I also have a T450s. Something goes wrong somewhere in the dns stack for me intermittently.